# How do I change ITEMIZE ITEM STYLE to a ball with shadow as shown in the picture?

Tags: beamer, itemize, bullets

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[ball]
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With two screenshots from your image:

[image]
[image]

(with the original file, one could do better quality images)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[height=0.6em]{blueball}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\includegraphics[height=0.6em]{redball}}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item blub
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Second solution using `tikz`**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[ball color=blue!50!white, preaction={fill=black,
opacity=.25,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm, yscale=0.5}}] (0,0) circle (0.6ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \shade[ball color=red!50!white, preaction={fill=black,
        opacity=.25,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm, yscale=0.5}}] (0,0) circle (0.6ex);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item first item
    \item second item
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first item
        \item second item
    \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]